# Kong : missing database for connect

Tags: docker, kong

im trying to set up Kong for my company, i followed the instruction from Kong documentation.

first i run this command:

```
docker network create kong-net
```

and then this command:

```
docker run -d --name kong-database \
               --network=kong-net \
               -p 5432:5432 \
               -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
               -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
               -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong" \
               postgres:9.6
```

according to documentation, next step is run the migration with this command

```
docker run --rm --network=kong-net -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" -e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong" kong:latest kong migrations up
```

but it keeps giving me this error

```
Error: missing database for connect
```

full log

```
Error:
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:547: missing database for connect
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:547: in function 'send_startup_message'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:207: in function 'connect'
        .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:202: in function 'connect'
        .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:489: in function 'query'
        .../share/lua/5.1/kong/db/strategies/postgres/connector.lua:270: in function 'init'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/init.lua:138: in function 'init_connector'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:95: in function 'cmd_exec'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:45>
        /usr/local/bin/kong:9: in function 'file_gen'
        init_worker_by_lua:48: in function <init_worker_by_lua:46>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        init_worker_by_lua:55: in function <init_worker_by_lua:53>
2020/07/23 03:38:40 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong/kong.conf
2020/07/23 03:38:40 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong.conf
2020/07/23 03:38:40 [verbose] no config file, skip loading
2020/07/23 03:38:40 [verbose] prefix in use: /usr/local/kong
```

where did i go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this

Step : 1

```
docker run -d --name kong-database \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
    -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
    postgres:9.6
```

Step : 2

```
docker run --rm \
    --link kong-database:kong-database \
    -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
    -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
    -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" \
    kong kong migrations up
```

Step : 3

```
docker run -d --name kong \
    --link kong-database:kong-database \
    -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
    -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
    -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" \
    -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
    -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -p 8443:8443 \
    -p 8001:8001 \
    -p 8444:8444 \
    kong
```

you can also use this docker-compose if you don't have any issue

**Updated**

```
version: "2"

services:
  kong-database:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: kong-database
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: kong
      POSTGRES_USER: kong
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong

  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    command: "kong migrations bootstrap"
    restart: always
    links:
      - kong-database:kong-database
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8443:8443
      - 8001:8001
      - 7946:7946
      - 7946:7946/udp
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong
      - KONG_PG_USER=kong
```

if you require version 3.7 of docker compose

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60511959/5525824

Comment: you can add single line in docker compose. add a line like command: "kong migrations up"

Comment: using docker-compose i still get the missing database to connect error sir.

Comment: here officeial docker compose : https://github.com/Kong/docker-kong/tree/master/compose

Comment: if version issue there please use this one : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/docker-kong/2.0.2/compose/docker-compose.yml

Comment: please check the updated answer.... version 2 docker-compose working for me i have tested.